# Proper spacing for texts added in between date and abstract on the title page?

Tags: spacing, titles, line-spacing

As the code shown below, I want to add two lines between date and abstract head, while maintaining the proper spacing so that the title is moved towards the top. Right now, if my abstract is long enough, the spacing is crowded towards the bottom.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn]{article}       

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\title{How to add texts in between date and abstract to get proper spacing in title page?\thanks{Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.}}

\author{Adam Smith}
\medskip
\date{October 6, 2018}}
\maketitle

%%% How to add these two lines here to get proper spacing in title page?
\begin{center}{This is the first line}\end{center}
\begin{center}{This is the second line}\end{center}


%%%   ABSTRACT
\begin{abstract}
\noindent
This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.

\bigskip
\end{abstract}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can the title, name, date move up so that other things below have proper space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got inspired from this thread using vspace at proper places: [Shift title and author text up?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29593/shift-title-and-author-text-up)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,fleqn]{article}       

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

% spacing option
\title{\vspace{-1.0cm}How to add texts in between date and abstract to get proper spacing in title page?\thanks{Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.Thank StackExchange.}}

\author{Adam Smith}
\medskip
\date{October 6, 2018}}
\maketitle

%%% How to add these two lines here to get proper spacing in title page?
\begin{center}
\vspace{-1.0cm}       % spacing option
This is the first line \\
This is the second line
\vspace{0.5cm}        % spacing option
\end{center}


%%%   ABSTRACT
\begin{abstract}
\noindent
This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.This an abstract.

\bigskip
\end{abstract}
\setcounter{page}{0}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]