# Abstract and keywords too big to fit first page

Tags: formatting, titles

I have a title and abstract which respects the following codes length. I want to have the abstract and keywords at the first page, is there a way to make it fit nicely?

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace} 
 \doublespacing
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{A nice article about how to have a happy life in a savage world}


\author{Someone Happy\thanks{Nowhere University \texttt{myemail@somewhere.com}} \and Other Person \thanks{Faculty of Wisdom, University of some place, Earth. \texttt{myemail@somewhere.com}}}

\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
 \blindtext[1] BBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEHHHHHHHHHAAAAAAAAAAPPPPPPPYYYYYY
 \end{abstract}
 {\bf Keywords:} Something, Uplifiting, Cheerup!, you can do it, I trust you.

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Shift title and author text up?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29593/134144) could be intersting if you want to reduce the space above the title in order to allow title, authors, abstract and keywords to fit onto one page.

Comment: Yup works! Added \vspace{-2.0cm} to the title and fits very well. Thanks!

Comment: Suggestion: Don't run `\doublespacing` in the preamble and, instead, run it right before `\section{Introduction}`.

Comment: Off topic: If both `amsmath` and `amsthm` are used, load `amsmath1 *before* `amsthm`.

Comment: Thank you all! very helpful :))

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest you take the following approach:

- Remove the instruction `\doublespacing` from the preamble.
- Insert the instruction `\setstretch{1.5}` right before `\begin{abstract}`.
- Insert the instructions `clearpage\doublespacing` right before `\section{Introduction}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, draft]{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace} 
 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage {tikz}
\usepackage[skip=0pt]{caption}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\title{A nice article about how to have a happy life in a savage world}


\author{Someone Happy\thanks{Nowhere University \texttt{myemail@somewhere.com}} \and Other Person \thanks{Faculty of Wisdom, University of some place, Earth. \texttt{myemail@somewhere.com}}}

\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{abstract}
 \blindtext[1] BBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEHHHHHHHHHAAAAAAAAAAPPPPPPPYYYYYY
 \end{abstract}
 {\bf Keywords:} Something, Uplifiting, Cheerup!, you can do it, I trust you.

\clearpage
\doublespacing
\section{Introduction}
\blindtext[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Mico! Very grateful. Positive vibes towards you :)