# Shift title and author text up automatically to fit the margin?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, titles

I am trying to have a solution to shift the title page of an article up automatically (without having to set it up manually). Taking a look at the solution of [Shift title and author text up?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29593/shift-title-and-author-text-up/29594#29594) :

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}   % This is your set screw

\author{The Author}
\title{The Title}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Instead of manually adjusting the height as `\setlength{\droptitle}{-10em}` , is there a way to automatically adjust the hight with the next page's upper margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the solutions I have found seem to manually determine the vertical space to be eliminated. An "automatic" but in my opinion not so efficient way would be to redefine the `\@maketitle` defined by the `titling` package (even if in this way it becomes superfluous if it is used only for adjusting the title spacing):

```
  \def\@maketitle{%
    \newpage
    %\null
    %\vskip 2em%
    %      \vspace*{\droptitle}
    \maketitlehooka
    {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}
    \maketitlehookb
    {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}
    \maketitlehookc
    {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}
    \maketitlehookd
    \par
    \vskip 1.5em}
```

This can be done through `etoolbox` like in the next MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\author{The Author}
\title{The Title}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\null}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vskip 2em}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\vspace*{\droptitle}}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]